# Python calling both Java and C modules, howto?

Tags: python, jython

Jython calls Java modules, and C-language modules callable from Python. What if a Python/Jython program needs to call some modules in Java and some in C, any solution?

Comment: Use Jython and ctypes or JNA. Jython is definitely capable of using C libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jython partially supports ctypes in last builds, so you should check whether current support is enough for your needs.

If not, you can go with JNA, http://www.flester.com/blog/2009/02/21/java-jna-jythonjruby-the-sweet-spot